# how to provide input while running .sh interactive script using python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, stdin, popen

i am running a scripts using python that prompts for password and path while executing. When running the scripts from the command line, the behavior is below:

```
# obfuscatePassword.sh 
[Password to obfuscate:]
[Path of password file to be created:]passwd.txt
Password file successfully created at passwd.txt
#
```

I am wondering, I am not able to provide the input data from the python subprocess. Seems the way I am trying to provide those inputs using stdin isn't working. Please see below code:

```
-----
-----
obfuscatePassword = subprocess.Popen(['obfuscatePassword.sh'],
                                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     universal_newlines=True)
obfuscatePassword.stdin.write(password)
obfuscatePassword.stdin.write(passwordFilePath)
stdout, stderr = obfuscatePassword.communicate('through stdin to stdout')

-----
-----
```

the execution just hangs in console and I have to press ctrl + C to end the python program.

Can any one of you help me understand where I am coding wrong? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sending a newline character as well?

Comment: no. should i send newline in (['obfuscatePassword.sh\n'],

Comment: I don't know how your shell script looks exactly but it is worth try to add \n after stdin.write

Comment: Are you sending the string 'through stdin to stdout' to stdin, intentionally? Because that strikes me as a bit odd

Comment: no.. that is unintentional. I dont know the significance of that string... I am new to python world though

Comment: just FYI... Truncating the string 'through stdin to stdout' to stdin' in communicate method call or the adding new line in stdin.write method call is not helping out....